# Javascript - Slicing an array of objects

Tags: javascript, for-loop, slice

I'm returning an array of objects from an API which returns an array of 1380 objects, I only need the objects at index 116 - 137. I've researched into `Array.prototype.slice()`. From what I researched I believe you need to for loop through the current array in order to slice an array of objects which is what I am attempting to do.

I am trying to create a new array of objects of the ones that I need only. Which are index 116 - index 137. When console logging my new array after the splice method I am not getting anything returned in my console.

Here is my code

```
    function drawPercentageDifference(data) {


for (var i = 0; i < data.Results.Data; i++) {

    var caArray = data.Results.Data.slice(115, 137)

    console.log(caArray, "cAArray")

}
}
```

This is the result when console logging the original array

```
console.log(data.Results.Data)
Array(1380) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

For this situation is a for loop necessary?

I did originally try slicing like this

```
    function drawPercentageDifference(data) {

caArray = data.BEAAPI.Results.Data.toString().slice(115, 137)
console.log(caArray)
    }
}
```

which led to `forString is not a function` and my console.log for caArray returning `object object` but based on what I was reading I believe I am not able to because it is an array of objects and not of strings.

Comment: Why do you need to loop?

Comment: *When console logging my new array after the splice method I am not getting anything returned in my console.* If nothing logs, it sounds like the array is being populated asynchronously (though I"m surprised an error isn't thrown). Can you post more of the surrounding code, where the API call is made?

Comment: I do not know if I need to or not. I tried the slicing method down below and I was getting an error that 'toString' is not a function. After looking into that error I came across slicing using an for loop. If this is not necessary then that is fine with me I am just not sure on which steps I should be taking with trying to slice an array or objects

Comment: *after the splice method* <= also please verify that this was a typo with "splice"

Comment: Ok, so this sounds like an X/Y problem.  You encountered an error with slicing, so you tried to come up with a fix, and now you're having an issue with the attempted fix.  Please show us the original issue.

Comment: yes sorry this is a typo I am trying to use the `slice` method not splice.

Comment: If you want indexes 116-137, why are you slicing from 115?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue. Thank you to everyone who commented. the for loop was not necessary and after removing the .toString() method I received back to result I was expecting.

Final answer
`caArray = data.BEAAPI.Results.Data.slice(115, 137)
console.log(caArray)`